# Amarok2 “Search Collection” shortcut?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, search, amarok

Is there a way to make a shortcut for amarok2 that would put focus on the "search collection" box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so (you could submit a feature request), but you can use Ctrl-J ("Search playlist") and then Shift-Tab to get there. Not the most practical of solutions, but it works.